# toastr is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toastr

Receiving the following error in developer console when loading the page:

Uncaught ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Here are the html contents. Can someone please explain to me why toastr is undefined?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p>Toastr TEST</p>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script scr="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.2/js/toastr.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log("document.ready");
      toastr.info('document.ready');
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
      console.log("window.load");
      toastr.info('window.load');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why not include the `<script>`s in `<head>` too.

Comment: toastr is a plugin for alerts. You need to include the script that includes the references to toastr in your header.

Comment: @ShaunakD I tried adding the <script>s into the <head> but I'm still receiving the same errors. Thank you though.

Comment: The `<script>` element that references `toastr.js` contains a typo -- its `scr` attribute should be `src`.

Comment: @jonmrich Thank you for the suggestion. I tried moving http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.2/js/toastr.min.js into the '<head>' but am still receiving the same errors. Isn't that the correct file to include for the Toastr library?

Comment: This was my fault. Just a typo in the script tag for the toastr library. Thanks everyone.

Comment: In My case I just moved code from bottom to <header></header> element. problem solved. @shaunak D thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the script elemen's src attribute wrongly spelled for the toaster.js file, it should be "src" but is "scr".

Comment: Thank you so much. So sorry to waste everybody's time!!! I should have joined stackoverflow last week! I will accept answer as soon as it lets me. Have a great day.